# How to tell which layer of JSON request is the JSON object in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, node.js, json, fs, fetch-api

I need to copy the request of an API (received as a JSON object) into a new file. This file is structured as follows:

```
{
metadata:{},
data:[
  {},
  {},
  {}
]
}
```

To call the API, I am using the Fetch module, with the following code:

```
function getLowTides(date) {
  // pull from NOAA tide chart
  let url = https://tidesandcurrents.noaa.gov/api/datagetter?begin_date=20180705%2000:00&end_date=20180705%2023:59&station=9447130&product=water_level&datum=MSL&units=english&time_zone=lst_ldt&application=universityofwashington&format=json
  fetch(url) 
  .then((resp) => {
      return resp.json()
    })
  .then(content => {
    fs.writeFileSync(
        getTideChartFileName(date),
        JSON.stringify(content),
        (err) => {
          if (err) throw err
        }
      )
  })

  .catch(function(error){
      console.log(error)
  })

}
```

then using the FileSystem module to write a new file. My problem is that I can't tell what *exactly* `content` is (the console only says `object` when I use `typeof` in a fiddle, which is the same output as `content.data`). This leads to the file not being created, causing problems down the line.

I tested each part of this individually, and can verify that the url provided will indeed get you a page of JSON data.

I have also verified that `content.data` is another object, as well as `content.data[0]` and `content.data[0].t` will get the `t` attribute of the first entry in `data`. All of these are as I expected.

I have also tried writing in `content`, `content.data`, `JSON.stringify(content.data)` in place of `JSON.stringify(content)`, as well as a few other permutations that should have resulted in something, even if I didn't get the whole file.

The code for the file name is as such:

```
function getTideChartFileName(date){
    return __dirname + '/tidecharts/' +
    date.getFullYear() +
    '/' +
    (date.getMonth() + 1).toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    date.getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0") +
    '.json'
}
```

where the date used in the url (July 5, 2018) would return `__dirname + '/tidecharts/2018/0705.json'`. This is also working accurately, as I use the same function to look for the file in both readings and writings of it.

It is my understanding that fs.writeFileSync() is expecting a JSON object in it's second argument, which should be what is immediately returned from the API call. therefore, I should be able to immediately pass in `content` and have it work without a hitch. I don't believe I have to stringify it, since 1) that's not working, and 2) it was never explicitly parsed.

I am expecting for a .json file to be created at the directory `/tidecharts/2018/`, however I end up not creating a new file and end up with the predictable access errors when I try to read from the nonexistent file.

Please help me correct any misconceptions I have about any of this, and any guidance or specific reference materials are much appreciated.

Comment: This question isnt well structured. Plus I am not sure what your question is.

Comment: Your arguments to `writeFileSync` don't appear to be correct: https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1- writeFileSync doesn't have callback, it will block the code until writing the file, it will not return any thing, but it will return an error exception if something wrong, so you have to put it inside try catch block.

So you have to delete third parameter for write file, and put that code inside try catch block

2- writ file data should be one of the following `<string> | <Buffer> | <TypedArray> | <DataView>` , so you have to convert json to string.

3- to format stringify output `JSON.stringify(value[, replacer[, space]])` pass your object in first param, set second to null , third param will be spaces between , please check [ref](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/JSON/stringify#Parameters)

please check [node ref](https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html#fs_fs_writefilesync_file_data_options)

If you changed the code and still not find the file, please check how [__dirname works](https://alligator.io/nodejs/how-to-use__dirname/)

For an [example](https://stackabuse.com/reading-and-writing-json-files-with-node-js/)